# Saving vcl objects references in dephi with Tcollection

Tags: delphi, reference, tcollection

I am using delphi 2009 and VCL components. I have created a collection called
TStreets made of items TStreet which has just two private fields. Now I need to add
to Tstreet class another field/property to keep track (by using reference) of 
other objects of class TMyObject.

An example: let's assume that TStreet collection contains five elements and ten objects 
(TMyObject) exists in my application at run-time.  Each objects of TMyObject can belong 
to only one  TStreet so I need to save for each TStreet all reference of objects and
then be able to move one or more object reference from one TStreet to another.
Should I create another colletion under TStreet where saving object references?

Is it correct the way to go?

Comment: Are you actually using `TCollection` and `TCollectionItem`? Those classes are designed to help publish collections to the Object Inspector. Unless you actually want your Streets and YourObjects to be dropped on a form and manipulated at design time, you don't want `TCollection`

Comment: I can't make any sense of this. Perhaps I'm being particularly dumb today, but I wonder if you could try to make your question a little clearer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using TCollection as collection-type container, regardless of form designer interoperability.

Comment: "There is nothing wrong with using TCollection as collection-type container". Well, other than being compelled to make your members descend from `TCollectionItem` and having to take `TCollection`'s. rather designer-centric interface. `TObjectList` would be my personal choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the following.

```
TMyObject = class
  ...
end;

TStreet = class
 ...
 public
   property MyObject : TMyObject ...;
end;

TStreets = TList<TStreet>;
```

It appears from reading your question that a TMyObject can only be tied to one TStreet.

Then I would recommend reversing the references.

```
TStreet = class;

TMyObject = class
protected
  FStreet : TStreet;
public
  property Street : TStreet read FStreet write FStreet;
end;

TMyObjectList = TList<TMyObject>;

TStreet = class
 private
   // Looks through MyObjectList returning correct 
   function GetMyObjecty : TMyObject; reference.
 public
   property MyObject : TMyObject read GetMyObject;
   // Reference to list that contains all instance of TMyObjectList.
   property MyObjectList : TMyObjectList; 
end;

TStreets = TList<TStreet>;

TMyObjectList = TList<TMyObject>;
```

Comment: +1 because I like generics. But Delphi 2009 didn't have them so the OP can't use them.

Comment: they were introduced in D2009

Comment: It really does not matter how you define the collection, it's how to deal with the linking problem.